# time.ParseInLocation, location is nil

Tags: go

I am parsing a location like so:

```
estLocation, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
d, err := time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC3339, fmt.Sprintf("%sT%s:00.000Z", c.Date, c.Open), estLocation)
```

When I examine `d` after parsing, the time part looks fine (i.e. the string is parsed into the time I expect), but the location is `nil`.

Why is this? I need the time parsed as a new york time (so that I can call `.UTC()` on it and transform it into UTC time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Z at the end of your date string means "zulu", i.e. UTC time; so your time is explicitly indicating it's in UTC. See tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-2

If you pass a valid offset, you get a valid result: https://play.golang.org/p/QW8M3_eznDL

```
d, err := time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC3339, fmt.Sprintf("%sT%s:00.000+05:00", "2001-01-01", "12:34"), estLocation)
```

The docs indicate this accordingly (emphasis mine):

> **in the absence of time zone information**, Parse interprets a time as UTC; ParseInLocation interprets the time as in the given location

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation